# How to compute the difference between two dates in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table named `table1`. It has a column `NT_T_SENTDATE`. This column keeps dates. It has data since 2005. Therefore this table is so heavy.

I want to see the rows which date is from dec 2013 to dec 2014 in `NT_T_SENTDATE` column. I know there is `datediff` method, I have used this query for this:

```
select * 
from notificationtransactions 
where datediff(day, NT_D_SentDate, '2015-03-25') > 360
```

BUT it is also showing the records older than 2013.

Can someone please correct me? What should I add to the query so that I can see only records older than 1 year, but not older than 3 years?

Looking forward your response

POOJA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Query will return only this year records

```
 SELECT *
 FROM notificationtransactions 
 WHERE NT_T_SENTDATE> DATEADD(YY, -1, GETDATE())
```

This Query will return only Previous year records

```
   SELECT * 
   FROM notificationtransactions  
   WHERE  NT_T_SENTDATE BETWEEN
   DATEADD(YY, -2, GETDATE()) AND  DATEADD(YY, -1, GETDATE())
```

Comment: [Why type `YY` instead of `YEAR`](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations.aspx)?

Comment: hi  @mahmoud, thanks for this , yes it is working as expect but i have one question what is the use of  DATEADD(YY, -1, GETDATE()). please tell

Comment: @AaronBertrand yy, yyyy are abbreviations for year, all are the same

Comment: @KhushiSharma, DATEADD is a tsql function that can used to add or subtract a specified time interval and accepts 3 parameters
1- [YY] stands for the interval type
2- [-1]  stands for the number to deducts or subtracts ( in your example it is negative, so it subtracts)
3- [GETDATE()]  stands for the orginal date (in our example it is  another tsql function that returns current date)
 To summarize the function take the current date and subtracts  one year from it.

Comment: @Mahmoud did you read my post about [why using abbreviations is bad](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.NotificationTransactions 
WHERE 
    NT_D_SentDate <= '20140325' 
    AND NT_D_SentDate >= '20130101'
```

It shows all records with a "sent date" between Jan 1, 2013 and one year ago.